# json_encode escape special characters

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays

I would like to pass a `php` array to a `jQuery` function.
I tried to send the array as `json_encode` like this:

```
<button onclick='callFunction(<? echo json_encode($myArray); ?>)'></button>
```

the result of my json_encode array is:

```
{"Date":"2018-01-26 12:55:00","Details":"FORLI IT"}
```

All works good.

But if I have an array like this (with a `'`)

```
{"Date":"2018-01-26 12:55:00","Details":"FORLI' IT"}
```

My function doesn't work anymore - my console will show:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I suggest you deal with anything that goes to html is:

```
<button onclick='callFunction(<? echo htmlentities(json_encode($myArray),ENT_QUOTES); ?>)'></button>
```

Check all available flags at http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

This one uses the flag `ENT_QUOTES` because the default behaviour is to only encode double quotes. Using `ENT_QUOTES` will also encode single quotes.

Comment: problem still the same: SyntaxError: Unexpected EOF

Comment: Forgot the flag, try again

Comment: This looks much better !! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php),

```
<button onclick='callFunction(<? echo json_encode(addslashes($myArray)); ?>)'></button>
```

Comment: I tried this and check the echo. is it right, that after this process the echo is "null"?